# Filtering data in excel with embedded pictures

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data table with product images that I want to filter depending on who I send the spreadsheet to. The pictures are still visibly stacked on top of each other.

How do I set up my sheet so that when rows/products are hidden (via data filter), their corresponding pictures are also hidden?

Answer (score 7):

Change the Object Positioning property for each image first. On XL2007, you can do this by following these steps:

1. Right-click an image and click **Size and Properties**.
2. Go to the **Properties** tab.
3. Select **Move and Size with Cells**.

[image]

I suggest recording a macro to quickly do this for all of the images in your spreadsheet.

Make sure each image is positioned to appear as if they are "inside" a cell.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

**No active filters**
[image]

**Filtered by Name**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You can also use the Select button and select all the pictures by dragging a box around all pictures. Then right click properties etc., or
- Select one picture and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select All), then right click properties etc.

Excel seems to understand that when selecting one picture and you press Select all (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), you want to select all pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This was a very simple and effective way.

I would like to add on, that instead of using the macros, we can select the function Go To (Ctrl+ G), then select "Special", then select "Objects", and then click OK. This will simply select all the images in the spreadsheet. Maybe we didn't have this function in XL2007, but the newer versions definitely have it. Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with Excel 2016 and used a combination of answers to solve this:

1. Ctrl+G or F5
2. Select Special, then 'Objects' and click 'OK'
3. Right-click on one of the images and click Size and Properties
4. Select 'Move and size with cells' from 'Properties' and close
5. Done

HOWEVER ONLY filtering works, sorting doesn't work properly. I have three columns with images. If I sort the one in the middle A-Z, the right column will sort properly, but not the left one. The left one is either missing images or overlapping again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. There already is answer with the same solution. It is better to just upvote the existing answer instead of creating a duplicate.